# MSBuild copy or create file if not exists

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a simple requirement to create a file in the project directory called user.config, but only if it doesn't exist already.

First attempt:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Line Include="line01"><Text>&lt;appSettings&gt;&lt;/appSettings&gt;</Text></Line>
      <LineText Include="%(Line.Text)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <WriteLinesToFile File="user.config" Lines="@(LineText)" Overwrite="false" />
  </Target>
```

**Doesn't work because it appends to file**

Second attempt:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <CreateItem Include="user_example.config">
      <Output ItemName="ItemsThatNeedToBeCopied" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ItemsThatNeedToBeCopied)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)" Condition="!Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>
```

**Doesn't work because nothing seems to happen and there is nothing in the verbose msbuild output telling me anything about why**

Any MSBuild expert should easily see what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: How about changing last line in first attempt to `<WriteLinesToFile File="user.config" Lines="@(LineText)" Overwrite="True" Condition="!Exists('user.config')"/>`? Also to figure out why the second doesn't work crank up the verbosity (pass /v:d on the command line) and/or add a Message task in which you show things like %(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename)%(Extension)

Comment: @Stijn, changing the last line in the first attempt worked like a charm. You may add it as an answer and I will reward you the correct answer here.

Comment: @stijn. Hope you see this.

Comment: yes if you use the `@` the user in question gets a notification

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first attempt is pretty much the canonical way to do this and you basically got it right except for the missing condition (which every MsBuild task supports):

```
<WriteLinesToFile File="user.config" Lines="@(LineText)" Overwrite="True"
                  Condition="!Exists('user.config')"/>
```