# MSBuild create folder if folder does not exists

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854860/msbuild-copy-or-create-file-if-not-exists), but rather than creating a file if it doesn't exist - I want to create a folder, if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> MSBuild create folder if folder does not exists

To create a folder if folder does not exists, you can use the below xml code:

```
  <Target Name="MakeMyDir" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)Newfolder" Condition="!Exists('$(ProjectDir)Newfolder')"  />
  </Target>
```

**Newfolder** is the name of your created folder.